# Input Mismatch Exception problem with code

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble here. Basically, I am given the line of input

```
5,4 4,5 8,7=6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3=7,6=9,8=5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4
```

I am splitting by the `=`, then adjusting the coordinates, adding them back to array rows and shifting them either forward or backward.

The problem is, as soon as I start my program, it throws an input mismatch exception and not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
public class Pirate {
    
    int singleCoordinateX;
        int singleCoordinateY;
        PrintStream out;
        String position;
        Coordinate coordinates;
        CoordinateRow newSplitStringRow;
        String splitString;
        CoordinateRow adjustedSplitStringRow;
        CoordinateRow newAdjustedSplitStringRow;
    
    Pirate() {
    out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    position = "front";
            newSplitStringRow = new CoordinateRow();
            adjustedSplitStringRow = new CoordinateRow();
            newAdjustedSplitStringRow = new CoordinateRow();
    }
    
void start() {

    Scanner newCoordinateInputData = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();

    String singleLineInputString = newCoordinateInputData.nextLine();

    splitLineString(singleLineInputString);

    printCoordinateRow();
}


void splitLineString(String singleLineInputString) {

    String[] newSingleLineStringArray = singleLineInputString.split("=");

    for(int i = 0; i < newSingleLineStringArray.length; i++) {

        splitString = newSingleLineStringArray[i];
        
        Scanner splitStringScanner = new Scanner(splitString);
        
        newCoordinateRow(splitStringScanner);
        
        placeCoordinateRow(newCoordinateRow(splitStringScanner));
    }
        
}


CoordinateRow newCoordinateRow(Scanner splitStringScanner) {
    
    splitStringScanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
    
    while(splitStringScanner.hasNext()) {
        
        String coordinateString = splitStringScanner.next();
        
        coordinates = convertCoordinates(coordinateString);
        
        newSplitStringRow.addSingleCoordinateToBack(coordinates);
        
    }
    
    return newSplitStringRow;
    
}

Coordinate convertCoordinates(String coordinateString) {
    
    Scanner coordinateScanner = new Scanner(coordinateString);
    
    coordinateScanner.useDelimiter(",");
    
    while(coordinateScanner.hasNext()) {
        
        singleCoordinateX = coordinateScanner.nextInt();
        
        singleCoordinateY = coordinateScanner.nextInt();
        
        coordinates = new Coordinate(singleCoordinateX, singleCoordinateY);
    }
    
    return coordinates;
}



CoordinateRow placeCoordinateRow(CoordinateRow adjustedSplitStringRow) {

    if(position == "front") {

        newAdjustedSplitStringRow.addCoordinateRowFront(adjustedSplitStringRow);

        position = "back";

    } else if(position == "back") {

        newAdjustedSplitStringRow.addCoordinateRowBack(adjustedSplitStringRow);

        position = "front"; 
    }

    return newAdjustedSplitStringRow;

}

void printCoordinateRow() {

    for(int i = 0; i < newAdjustedSplitStringRow.numberOfElements; i++) {

        out.printf("%d, %d\n", newAdjustedSplitStringRow.newCoordinateArray[i].coordinateX, newAdjustedSplitStringRow.newCoordinateArray[i].coordinateY);           
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Pirate.Pirate.convertCoordinates(Pirate.java:81)
    at Pirate.Pirate.splitLineString(Pirate.java:63)
    at Pirate.Pirate.start(Pirate.java:47)
    at Pirate.Pirate.main(Pirate.java:257)
```

Output I am getting:

```
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
8, 6
10, 8
6, 5
8, 8
7, 5
7, 4
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
8, 6
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
8, 6
10, 8
```

Output I should be getting

```
6,5
8,8
7,5
7,4
8,6
6,4
5,5
9,7
7,3
4,2
10,6
5,3
10,8
```

I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: Please add the exception stack trace, it says why. Also, some of your global members/variables are not shown in your code.

Comment: Done. I have added the exceptions.

Comment: Which line is line 81 of your program? The stack trace says it tries to read an int there but can’t.

Comment: that is nextInt

Comment: You are calling `nextInt()` twice. Which one of them?

Comment: That was for the x coordinate and one for the y coordinate

Comment: I have re edited my code with the output. But for some reason, I am getting alot more output then i should be getting. Any ideas?

It seems to be converting the coordinates what I want, but then outputting more coordinates then it should. Am i overlooping somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are two types of coordinate value delimiters, commas and blanks.

You should change

```
splitStringArrayScanner.useDelimiter(",");
```

to

```
splitStringArrayScanner.useDelimiter(",|\\s+");
```

Comment: O that worked, but it seems to print out my output twice

Comment: This is the output I get vs what is expected.

(EXPECTED)
6,5
8,8
7,5
7,4
8,6
6,4
5,5
9,7
7,3
4,2
10,6
5,3
10,8

(MINE)

6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
8, 6
10, 8
6, 5
8, 8
7, 5
7, 4
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
8, 6
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
6, 4
5, 5
9, 7
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
8, 6
10, 8

Comment: I have re-edited my code, but I seem to be getting alot more output then i  should. Any ideas?

Comment: Now your "Input Mismatch Exception problem with code" has been resolved, it's a good idea to repost it as another question.

Comment: Well I would if my other thread was not closed.